# Looking for the correct Envelope Transfer Rules Request Body Payload for UPDATE Call

Tags: docusignapi

I am looking for the right/correct Envelope Transfer Rules Request Payload for UPDATE Call. I have created this following JSON body-payload but it's throwing this error: {
"errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
"message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. The specified 'envelopeTransferRuleId' (770246) cannot be modified."
}

Here is the Payload which I am using to update this existing Envelope Tranfer Rules: Any Suggestion?

```
{ "envelopeTransferRules": [
        {
            "envelopeTransferRuleId": "770246",
            "eventType": "beforeSent",
            "carbonCopyOriginalOwner": "false",
            "enabled": "true",
            "fromUser": {
                "userId": "87yu5cfr6-e865-40cd-8d39-XXXXXX-XXXX",
                "userType": "CompanyUser",
                "userStatus": "Active",
                "email": "USER-1@test.com",
                "defaultAccountId": "1b035ccb-1a73-4c79-XXc9-XXXXXXXXXXX"
                
            },
            "toUser": {
                "userId": "b473b810-eaXX-406f-a423-XXXXXXXXXX",
                "userType": "CompanyUser",
                "userStatus": "Active",
                "email": "USER-2@test.com",
                "defaultAccountId": "1b035ccb-1a73-4c79-XXc9-XXXXXXXXXXX"
                
            },
            "toFolder": {
                "name": "Inbox"
                
            }
            
        }
        
    ]
    
   }
```

I am looking for the right/correct Envelope Transfer Rules Request Payload for UPDATE Call. I have created this following JSON body-payload but it's throwing this error: {
"errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
"message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. The specified 'envelopeTransferRuleId' (770246) cannot be modified."
}

Here is the Payload which I am using to update this existing Envelope Tranfer Rules: Any Suggestion?

```
{ "envelopeTransferRules": [
        {
            "envelopeTransferRuleId": "770246",
            "eventType": "beforeSent",
            "carbonCopyOriginalOwner": "false",
            "enabled": "true",
            "fromUser": {
                "userId": "87yu5cfr6-e865-40cd-8d39-XXXXXX-XXXX",
                "userType": "CompanyUser",
                "userStatus": "Active",
                "email": "USER-1@test.com",
                "defaultAccountId": "1b035ccb-1a73-4c79-XXc9-XXXXXXXXXXX"
                
            },
            "toUser": {
                "userId": "b473b810-eaXX-406f-a423-XXXXXXXXXX",
                "userType": "CompanyUser",
                "userStatus": "Active",
                "email": "USER-2@test.com",
                "defaultAccountId": "1b035ccb-1a73-4c79-XXc9-XXXXXXXXXXX"
                
            },
            "toFolder": {
                "name": "Inbox"
                
            }
            
        }
        
    ]
    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update transfer rules, this is not supported by either the web app or the API, see here:[image]
You can delete a rule and add another one instead, there's no need to update the one you have.

To delete a rule use this:

```
DELETE [[BasePath]]restapi/v2.1/accounts/[[AccountID]]/envelopes/transfer_rules/[[envelopeTransferRuleId]]
```

[To create a rule use this:](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopetransferrules/create/)

```
POST [[BasePath]]/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/transfer_rules
```

The JSON to create a rule looks like this:

```
{"eventType":"completed","toUser":{"userId":"2022b285-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-889fc49bb277"},"toFolder":{"folderId":"63eca3c5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-10c7251928ee"},"carbonCopyOriginalOwner":true,"enabled":true,"fromUsers":[{"userId":"9cb13e29-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6baeba17505c"}]}
```

You need to find the UserID (GUIDs) for the users you are moving envelopes to/from.

Comment: The requirement is, need to change the ownership whenever a new Envelope is created through the API ("status":"created"}. 

API call will be invoked in the specific conditions and the document should be added later because of the serious privacy control. If the ownership is not transferred, the Document Owner can't use the just-created envelope for the rest of the work before sent. The idea was to create Transfer_Rules through DocuSign UI and update it every time when a new Envelope was created and the user who triggered the API, can see the unsent envelope under the Manage > Envelope.

Comment: Just delete it and create a new one, why does it have to be the same rule? doesn't make any difference

Comment: Can I delete and create a new one through an API call? But the challenge is how the API will find the Envelope_rules ID which needs to be deleted.

Comment: Yes, you can delete from API, when you create a rule the JSON you get back has envelopeTransferRuleId which you can store and then use for the delete

Comment: DELETE [[BasePath]]restapi/v2.1/accounts/[[AccountID]]/envelopes/transfer_rules/[[envelopeTransferRuleId]]

Comment: I can update my answer with this information if that helps

Comment: Thanks @inbar Gazit !! Can you also share with me the sample working payload to create Envelope Rules?

Comment: It is in https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopetransferrules/create/

Comment: Let me update the answer